# Android Studio GoogleAppEngine backend Maven error

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, maven-3, google-cloud-messaging

Ok well I have been up and down the internet looking for an answer.

I have maven installed on my mac and have set the path variables using:

```
   export M2_HOME=/opt/local/share/java/maven3
   export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
   export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

My maven details:

```
   Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 
   2013-02-19    13:51:28+0000)
   Maven home: /opt/local/share/java/maven3
   Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
   Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
   OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

However when I run the generate cloud backend tool I am greeted with this beautifully frustrating error.

http://goo.gl/FIdXvF

This is a view of my Maven setting prefs:

http://goo.gl/8eWmq7

As you can see I have tried to set the path variables using 'export' in the terminal and then I tried to manually point to it. This is so frustrating!!

Could someone let me know if I have missed something? I feel totally exhausted have been scouring stackoverflow and google groups for the last few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line

```
setenv M2_HOME /opt/local/share/java/maven3
```

to

```
/etc/launchd.conf
```

and restart your machine.

This makes M2_HOME visible to all apps installed on your mac.
Any vars you export in .bash_profile, are only exported to the shell, and not visible to any other installed apps.

Comment: Cool, cheers now AS is looking for the depreciated gcm.jar file?? This day just keeps getting better..

Comment: I solved it by checking obsolete packages in Android SDK Manager, and installing Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library. To be honest, I'm not sure why it wants to use that, instead of Play Services SDK.